# Regularity up to boundary of a solution $u\in W^{1,p}\cap W^{2,2}(\Omega;\Bbb R^m)$ to $\Delta^2 u = -\text{div}\, F$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^n$ be a $C^{2}$ domain (open and bounded) and let $p\in(1,\infty)$. Suppose $u\in W^{1,p}\cap W^{2,2}(\Omega;\Bbb R^m)$ is a weak solution to the fourth-order elliptic system
$$
\Delta^2 u = -\text{div}\, F
$$
in the sense that for any $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\Omega;\Bbb R^m)$, we have
$$
\int_{\Omega}\sum_{i,\alpha,\beta}  (\partial_{\alpha} \partial_{\beta}u^i) (\partial_{\alpha} \partial_{\beta}\varphi^i) \,dx 
= \int_{\Omega}\sum_{i,\alpha} F^i_\alpha (\partial_{\alpha}\varphi^i) \,dx.  
$$
Here $F$ is only assumed to be in $L^{q}(\Omega;\Bbb R^{m\times n})$, where $1/p+1/q=1$.

Naively, it appears to me that we can expect $u$ to be of class $W^{3,r}_{loc}$ for some suitable $r$, at least in the interior of $\Omega$. As for the regularity up to boundary, I am even less sure about what kind of constraints are needed to guarantee sufficient regularity.

> Q: What are some papers or monographs that cover this kind of topic?

For example, what kind of boundary regularity can we expect from assuming that $u|_{\partial \Omega} = \text{Tr}(w)$ for some $w\in W^{1,p}\cap W^{2,2}(\Omega;\Bbb R^m)$? Would assuming that $w\in C^1(\bar{\Omega};\Bbb R^m)$ be enough to conclude that $u \in C^1(\bar{\Omega};\Bbb R^m)$? Do we need to assume more regularity on $\partial \Omega$ or can we even drop it down to the class $C^{1,1}$?

Note that I am only interested in the regularity aspect of such a solution $u$. I won't mind if the reference doesn't mention the existence theory.

Comment: This is in regards to the example that you mention after your question. Perhaps I'm off the mark, but isn't it illusory to aim for $u$ more regular than its proposed boundary values? The Sobolev inequalities don't allow embedding $W^{2,2}$ inside $C^1$ in general.

Comment: @LeoMoos You are right, that was a bad example. Let me amend that a bit to reflect what I actually wanted to say.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this can't be found in the literature on biharmonic maps; perhaps you could explain where the literature falls short? For example, concerning interior regularity there is a paper of Chang-Wang-Yang entitled 'A regularity theory for biharmonic maps' that states the bound $\lvert w \rvert_{3,q} \leq C \lvert F \rvert_{0,q}$, at least when $w = 0$ and $\partial_\nu w = 0$ on the boundary.